# How to render HTML to the user of a step function endpoint?

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

I'm using serverless and https://github.com/horike37/serverless-step-functions to try and implement a system that is hit by a user, returns HTML based on a database entry for the params provided and then moves to a second function that writes to the database (without forcing the user to wait).

I think a step function in the right approach but I can't seem to get it to return HTML - it always returns a JSON body with the `executionArn` and `startDate`. e.g.

```
{
  "executionArn": "arn:aws:states:us-west-2:.......etc...",
  "startDate": 1513831673.779
}
```

Is it possible to have my html body return? At the moment my lambda function returns a simple h1 tag:

```
'use strict';

module.exports.requestHandler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    },
    body: `<h1>Success!</h1>`,
  };

  callback(null, response);
};
```

This is the state machine I'm aiming to create.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going for a react/angular/vue frontend hosted e.g. on S3/CDN that uses serverless for backend queries only, instead of rendering dynamic HTML through Lambdas. The 'standard' approach allows you to build apps that are much more responsive and can benefit from e.g. CDNs.

See e.g. https://www.slideshare.net/mitocgroup/serverless-microservices-real-life-story-of-a-web-app-that-uses-angularjs-aws-lambda-and-more or https://serverless-stack.com/

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the suggestion but doesn’t quite fit as the system is actually the backend of a link shortener.

Comment: Did you consider using AWS Lambda instead, there you can return HTML, while you can put a message into SNS to handle writ to the db separately from the main link shortener thread?